# Spyder frozen when using dype karg

Tags: python, freeze, spyder, genfromtxt

I am having a problem when using the Ipython interpreter of Spyder,

basically when I run the following lines,

```
import numpy as np

my_data=np.genfromtxt(path_to_my_file,delimiter="\t",skip_header=1,dtype='str')
```

The whole of Spyder gets frozen.

I does not happen when I run the line on Ipython using the console. I have been testing what is causing Spyder to freeze and it is the kwarg dtype='str'

If I add that **kwarg, it freezes, and everything works fine if I don't.

Any idea of how to solve it or why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I have just closed the variable explorer and now it is working, 
Thanks to https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/3139#issuecomment-215064619